# Selenium Java - anyway of know whether the browser is minimized?

Tags: selenium

I am using Selenium with Java. Is there a way to know whether the browser of the webdriver is minimized?

Answer (score 0):

you can use getSize() to get the window size, like this

> ```
> Dimension d= driver.manage().window().getSize();//returns of the browser window dimension
> System.out.println(d);
> ```